# Modify this java class to output AAC instead of MP3

Tags: java, audio, mp3, extract, aac

I have two different FLV videos. The first video's audio is encoded in MP3 format and the second video's audio is encoded as AAC. I have found a java class that I have successfully used to strip the MP3 from the first FLV video. Can this class be modified to strip the AAC audio from the second FLV video as well? I've tried many things and nothing so far has worked and I'm simply out of any further ideas. Hopefully I am just missing something simple and making a dumb mistake that is easy to correct. Any help at all is very much so appreciated! Thank you!

Here is the link to the java class: http://youtensils.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/youtensils-plugin/src/org/youtensils/client/plugin/audio/FlvAudioStream.java

Answer (score 1):

http://moitah.net/ for Extracting video and audio from FLV files without decompressing or recompressing

Answer (score 0):

you can try using JAAD to decode AAC from a video file..
[here is a link](http://jaadec.sourceforge.net/index.php) to the site.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, that is a MP4 demultiplexer, but I need a java FLV demultiplexer. :/